# Constructing/making a generic type and turning a type constraint into a struct-as-base-type constraint

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, type-constraints, generic-constraints

Normally we cannot constrain a type parameter `T` to deriving from a sealed type (such as a `struct` type). This would be meaningless because there is only one type which could fit, and as such there is no need for generics. So constraints like:

```
where T : string
```

or:

```
where T : DateTime
```

are illegal, for a very good reason.

However, when constraining to another type parameter, this can sometimes happen when that other type parameter is "substituted" into an actual type (which happens to be sealed). Consider the class:

```
abstract class ExampleBase<TFromType>
{
  internal abstract void M<TFromMethod>(TFromMethod value) where TFromMethod : TFromType;
}
```

which is quite innocent. In the concretization:

```
class ExampleOne : ExampleBase<string>
{
  internal override void M<TFromMethod>(TFromMethod strangeString)
  {
    var a = string.IsNullOrEmpty(strangeString);
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    var b = strangeString.Substring(10, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
  }
}
```

we make `TFromType` equal to `string`. This could be meaningful wrt. other members than `M<>`. But `M<>` itself can still be used: The code:

```
  var e1 = new ExampleOne();
  e1.M("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

will run and write:

```
False
kl
```

to the console. So the constraint essentially became `where TFromMethod : string`, but things were still fine.

This question is about what happens if `TFromType` is a value type. So this time we do:

```
class ExampleTwo : ExampleBase<DateTime>
{
  internal override void M<TFromMethod>(TFromMethod strangeDate)
  {
    // var c = DateTime.SpecifyKind(strangeDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);  // will not compile
    // var d = strangeDate.AddDays(66.5);  // will not compile

    var e = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:D}", strangeDate);  // OK, through boxing
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    var f = object.ReferenceEquals(strangeDate, strangeDate);
    Console.WriteLine("Was 'strangeDate' a box? " + f);
  }
}
```

**So why are the calls from the `c` and `d` declarations not allowed?** After all `strangeDate` has compile-time type `TFromMethod` which is constrained to be a `DateTime`. So surely `strangeDate` is implicitly a `DateTime`? After all, this worked with `string` (`class ExampleOne` above).

I would prefer an answer which referred to the relevant place in the official C# Language Specification.

Note that when trying to add `d`, typing `strangeDate.Ad`... makes IntelliSense (Visual Studio's autocompleter) come up with a list of all accessible instance members of `DateTime`, so clearly IntelliSense thinks the call in `d` should be legal!

Of course, after `c` and `d` have been commented out, we can use `ExampleTwo` (with `e` and `f`), and the code:

```
  var e2 = new ExampleTwo();
  e2.M(new DateTime(2015, 2, 13));
```

runs and writes out:

```
Friday, 13 February 2015
Was 'strangeDate' a box? False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the C# 5.0 specification:

> **6.1.10 Implicit conversions involving type parameters**
>
> The following implicit conversions exist for a given type parameter `T`:
>
> - From `T` to its effective base class `C`, from `T` to any base class of `C`, and from `T` to any interface implemented by `C`. [...]
> - [...]
>
> **10.1.5 Type parameter constraints**
>
> The effective base class of a type parameter `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - If `T` has no *class-type* constraint but has one or more *type-parameter* constraints, its effective base class is the most encompassed type (§6.4.2) in the set of effective base classes of its *type-parameter* constraints. The consistency rules ensure that such a most encompassed type exists.
> - [...]
>
> For the purpose of these rules, if `T` has a constraint `V` that is a *value-type*, use instead the most specific base type of `V` that is a *class-type*. This can never happen in an explicitly given constraint, but may occur when the constraints of a generic method are implicitly inherited by an overriding method declaration or an explicit implementation of an interface method.
>
> These rules ensure that the effective base class is always a *class-type*.

In other words, given a `where U : T` constraint with `T = string`, the effective base class of `U` is `string`. Given a `where U : T` constraint with `T = DateTime`, the effective base class of `U` is not `DateTime`, but `ValueType`. And the only relevant implicit conversion of a type parameter is from the type parameter type to its effective base class.

This does seem to lead to some rather odd behaviour, as you've found, but it must nonetheless have been a conscious decision, as it has been explicitly spelled out to behave the way you've seen.

I would guess that making this work caused difficulties in the compiler, that there are cases where the compiler assumes that it's dealing with a reference type in such cases, and that there is only minimal benefit in making it work. That's just that, though: a guess.

Comment: This answer seems correct! Since `ValueType` does not introduce many members, I tried changing from `DateTime` (a struct) to an enum instead. In particular, with `class ExampleTwo : ExampleBase<DateTimeStyles>` where [`DateTimeStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx) is an enum, I can use `d` as in `var d = strangeDateTimeStyles.HasFlag(DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);`, and it compiles. So the "effective base class" is indeed `System.Enum` which declares an instance method `HasFlag(Enum)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C#5 chapter `13.4.3 Implementation of generic methods`, it's said :

```
interface I<C>
{
    void H<T>(T t) where T: C;
}

class C: I<string>
{
    void H<T>(T t) 
    {
        string s = t;   // Ok
    }
}
```

They say :

> Note that the assignment from t to s is valid since T inherits a constraint of T: string, even though this constraint is not expressible in source code.

I understand this as : "you can write it, declare it, even if you can't use it"

Here String is a reference type, when we write `s = t`, we assign the reference, it's valid to assign, because the `where T: C` constraint allow it.

In the case of DateTime, when we write `s = t`, we copy the value, not the reference.

Comment: OK, but they **can** use their constraint. They do not say that if we had used `I<DateTime>` instead of `I<string>` then the inherited constraint of `T: DateTime` would **not** allow `DateTime s = t` (assignment from `t` to `s`), do they?

Comment: I think that's because String is a reference type that behave like a struct type, and DateTime is just a value type.

Comment: That is for sure. My question is, simply, why is it OK for reference types (like `string`), and not OK for value types (`DateTime`)?

Comment: because the equals operators for value references creates a copy of the value, not of the reference. and since there's no way to copy DateTime to T, the compiler checks it.

Comment: It think the problem is more, "why is it allowed with String", than "why it doesn't works with DateTime". In my opinion, it's a lack on compile-time constraint checking for the String case.